# Among the first 10,000 multiples of 17

Tags: functions, conditional, number-theory

Hello I'm new with Mathematica and I can't find a way where I can do this condition.

Among the first 10,000 multiples of 17 how many have the sum of their digit multiple of 17?

The part for the digit I should be able to do it but the first part is hard for me. Thanks for the future help.

Comment: Wellcome here! You need to generate 10,000 multiples of 17 and then select the ones that fulfill your condition.  The first task can be done with `Table`. You generate digits with `IntegerDigits`. `Mod` computes the reminder and can tell you whether they are multiples of 17.

Answer (score 6):

I am curious what do you need this problem for? You can write a function for arbitrary numbers:

```
multSUM[n_,m_]:=Select[Table[m k,{k,n}],Divisible[Total[IntegerDigits[#]],m]&]
```

Then for exactly your problem, 100 first results:

```
Multicolumn[multSUM[10^4,17][[;;100]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) can be used. For example,

```
r = Reap[Table[
     Sow[17 j, IntegerDigits[17 j] // Total], {j, 1, 10000}], 17][[2, 
    1]];
```

This yields 452 integers. Showing first 100:

```
Partition[r[[1 ;; 100]], 10] // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This works (at least to the limited extent that I have tested it) ...

```
17 Flatten[Position[Total/@IntegerDigits/@(17 Range[10000]),17]]
```

To understand it, pick it apart from the inside out, ie first figure out

```
Range[10000]
```

(start with a number of multiples smaller than 10k) then

```
17 Range[10000]
```

then

```
IntegerDigits/@(17 Range[10000])
```

and so for the